# Exception organization assistance?

Tags: java

I had some success with this site, and I hope I find more excellent programmers to assist me.

So I am at my wit's end with this code. I am very new to programming, especially exceptions. I have looked very hard through my course material and sought help, but I have been quite unsuccessful. I am trying to create an improved parser that will override another parser. It reads a .txt file with student information of it including an ID, a name, a grade, and an optional email address and optional comment as tokens in a String separated by commas. The override checks for errors in each token and throws an exception called ParserException. The exception will check the code and then return an error message if the error is unfixable.

For example, if a student puts in an AB for the grade, the exception will flag and check if the input is a valid grade (which it is) and then return, if it is not, then it will throw a ParserException, in this case
 `throw new ParserException(ParserException.GRADE_INVALID_GRADE,lineIndex);`
This shows that the does not work and sends out a message `GRADE_INVALID` on the line `indexLine`

I have a list of what I need to have as an output:

- Any violation of the file format specified in the Input File Format Description section above should result in an ParcerException with an appropriate message
- Duplicate IDs are not allowed
- Grade values must be a float (92.0) or a letter grade and not an integer

I have all the code to correct and check for errors, but I cannot figure out how to get the try-catch to work. Here's is the override code:

```
@Override
    public ParserResult parseLine(int lineIndex) {    
        String[] tokens = lines.get(lineIndex).split(",");
        ArrayList<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer studentId;
        String name;
        String grade;
        String email;
        String comments;
        boolean isFloat;
        float gradeFinal;
        String editName;
        studentId = new Integer(tokens[0]);
        ParserResult result;

        try{
            return super.parseLine(lineIndex);
        }
        catch(ParserException e){

            // Check reasonable number of tokens
            if(tokens.length >= 3 && tokens.length <= 5){

                name = tokens[1];
                grade = tokens[2];

                // Check the student ID
                if(idList.contains(studentId)){
                    throw new ParserException(ParserException.DUPLICATE_ID, lineIndex);
                }else{
                    idList.add(studentId);
                }

                // Check the grade
                if(grade.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
                    gradeFinal = gradeA;
                }else if(grade.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("AB")){
                    gradeFinal = gradeAB;
                }else if(grade.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
                    gradeFinal = gradeB;
                }else if(grade.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("BC")){
                    gradeFinal = gradeBC;
                }else if(grade.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
                    gradeFinal = gradeC;
                }else if(grade.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("CD")){
                    gradeFinal = gradeCD;
                }else if(grade.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
                    gradeFinal = gradeD;
                }else if(grade.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("F")){
                    gradeFinal = gradeF;
                }else{
                    try{
                        Integer.parseInt(grade);
                        isFloat = false;
                    }
                    catch(Exception fl) {
                        isFloat = true;
                    }
                    if(isFloat){
                        if((Float.parseFloat(grade) < 100f) && (Float.parseFloat(grade) >= 0f)){
                            gradeFinal = Float.parseFloat(grade);
                        }else{
                            throw new ParserException(ParserException.GRADE_INVALID_GRADE,lineIndex);
                        }
                    }else{
                        throw new ParserException(ParserException.GRADE_INTEGER_VALUE,lineIndex);
                    }
                }

                // Check the name
                if(name.split(" ").length > 3){
                    throw new ParserException(ParserException.UNKNOWN, lineIndex);
                }else{
                    editName = name.trim().split(" ")[0];
                }

                result = new ParserResult(studentId, editName, gradeFinal);

                // Checks the email
                if(tokens.length >= 4){
                    email = tokens[3];

                    // Check for at sign
                    if(!email.contains("@")){
                        throw new ParserException(ParserException.UNKNOWN, lineIndex);
                    }


                    int count = 0;
                    // Counts number of @ symbols
                    for(int i=0; i<email.length(); i++){
                        if(email.indexOf(i) == '@'){
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(count > 1){
                        throw new ParserException(ParserException.EMAIL_MULTIPLE_AT,lineIndex);
                    }
                    if(email.split(".").length == 2){
                        if(!(email.trim().split(".")[1].contains(".edu")) && !(email.trim().split(".")[1].contains(".com"))){
                            throw new ParserException(ParserException.EMAIL_NOT_EDU_OR_COM,lineIndex);
                        }else{
                            result.setEmail(email);
                        }
                    }
                    // Checks if email contains .com or .edu

                    // Checks the comments
                    if(tokens.length == 5){
                        comments = tokens[4];
                        result.setComment(comments);
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }

        // TODO Call Parser's parseLine() here to attempt to parse, catch any exceptions

        return null;
    }
```

The original parseLine that is overridden, but still used is:

```
public ParserResult parseLine(int lineIndex) {
    String[] tokens = lines.get(lineIndex).split(",");
    ParserResult result = new ParserResult(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]),
            tokens[1], Float.parseFloat(tokens[2]));
    result.setEmail(tokens[3]);
    return result;
}
```

Here is the main() file:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    // TODO Change the line below to use ImprovedParser 
    Parser parser = null;
    try {
        parser = new ImprovedParser(args[0]);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    List<ParserResult> results = parser.parse();

    int count = results.size();
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (ParserResult result : results) {
        sum += result.getGrade();
    }

    System.out.println("Number of valid input lines: " + results.size());
    System.out.println("Number of invalid input lines: "
            + (parser.getLineCount() - results.size()));
    System.out.println("Average grade: " + sum / count);
    for (ParserResult result : results) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Lastly, here is the .txt file that is being read:

```
# student_id,name,grade,email
1234,Bob,92.0,bob@test.edu
4321,Alice,95.0,alice@test.edu
1111,Eve,80.0,eve@test.edu
1121,Barry,85.0,barrytest.edu
1131,Harry,86.0,h@rry@test.edu
1121,Larry,87.0,larry@test.edu
1141,Jim Song,88.0,jim@song.edu
1151,Jerry,77.0,jerry@test.net
1161,James,65.0,james@test.com
```

The last six inputs should cause exceptions, but I can't figure out how to organize it to work. The code ignores the line with # symbol.

Here is a sample successful output:

```
Number of valid input lines: 3
Number of invalid input lines: 0
Average grade: 89.0
1234, 92.0, Bob, bob@test.edu,
4321, 95.0, Alice, alice@test.edu,
1111, 80.0, Eve, eve@test.edu,
```

The major changes should be in the orverride method
Please help if you can, I sit at my desk still pondering possibilities, and your help will be most-appreciated.

Comment: I feel like your problem can really be expressed in less than 20 lines of text. Please remove all the irrelevant information from the post and localize the problem. Also see this http://sscce.org/

Comment: First step is to clean up your code. Extract the individual parsing steps into their own methods (with appropriate `throws` clauses) so that the logic of the parsing process is legible and that you can test them individually. Also consider replacing your massive string comparison chain with an enum lookup.

Comment: @chryslis
I'm still new to programming (only a few months). Could you give me an example of what you mean? As this was an assignment, I cannot change anything else other than these methods. Still learning fundamentals...

Comment: @liberation First, use the autocomplete box in comments to ensure you spell names right; otherwise, I won't get a notification. What I mean is that each of the individual steps in the parsing should be its own method that gets called by `parseLine`; you can do this without breaking the interface you're programming to. For example, you'd have a method `float parseGrade(String grade)` that accepted a trimmed grade string and returned the appropriate number. This is much easier to test and makes your `parseLine` method easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ParseException` has an `error` field being an `int` and `someMethod()` that throws `ParseException`:

```
try {
    someMethod();
} catch (final ParseExeption ex) {
    if (ex.getError() == ParseException.SOME_ERROR) {
        // do something
    } else if (ex.getError() == ParseException.OTHER_ERROR) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Note that it's usually better to use specific exceptions for specific error, something like `SomeErrorParseException`, `OtherErrorParseException`, ... (those can extends `ParseException` if you want) and try-catch like this:

```
try {
    someMethod();
} catch (final SomeErrorParseException ex) {
    // do something
} catch (final OtherErrorParseException ex) {
    // do something else
}
```

Some reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no code to actually cause the `catch` clause in the first place. Try adding a `throw new ParserException(STUFF_HERE);` when an error has been detected while reading the file.